# Xcode: Play an audio file with music on the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova

I've build an iOS application with Cordova 3.6.3 that uses interface sounds. When you click on buttons the application plays a short "click"-sound. This works great. But when I use my application while music is playing on the background from another app this happens:
1. The background music fades out.
2. The interface sound is played.
3. The background music fades in.

This is not how it should happen. I would like to play interface-sounds while the background music is still on. What do I need to change to Cordova / Phonegap to change this behavior? Something with AVAudioSession?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution in **CDVSound.m**.

**Old version**

```
NSString* sessionCategory = bPlayAudioWhenScreenIsLocked ? AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback : AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient;
[self.avSession setCategory:sessionCategory error:&err];
```

**New version**

```
NSString* sessionCategory = bPlayAudioWhenScreenIsLocked ? AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient : AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient;
[self.avSession setCategory:sessionCategory error:&err];
```

Check https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionBasics/AudioSessionBasics.html for more info.